# Recuperar um componente gerado por um laço for em VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Estou começando em VueJS e não tenho ideia de como eu posso recuperar um elemento (se fosse em JS puro seria só armazenar em uma const e dp chamar pelo id), estou tentando fazer um jogo Monty Hall, e o q eu quero fazer é q quando a pessoa clicar em uma porta a anterior q estava selecionada perca a seleção automaticamente...
as portas são geradas em um laço for no componente principal

```
<div class="doors">
        <div
            v-for="i in doorsAmount"
            :key="i"
            @click="selected(i)"
            :id="'door' + i"
        >
            <Door :number="i" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Quando a div é clicada ela chama o método `selected(i)`, este método armazena o numero da nova porta selecionada e também deveria alterar um dado do componente porta para q a nova fosse selecionada e a anterior perdesse a seleção...

O componente porta tem os seguintes dados

```
data() {
    return {
        open: false,
        selected: false,
    };
},
```

Quando esse dado `selected` é alterado para true é q a porta fica marcada como selecionada por uma classe. Então como eu poderia fazer pra alterar esse componente da porta atual pra true e da anterior pra false, não sei como passar/alterar esse dado.... tentei colocar ele no props do componente porta mas como não consegui recupera o elemento tb não deu certo...
Como eu posso passar esse dado e como recuperar um elemento (porta anterior e atual) pra fazer essa passagem?
Dá pra fazer de algum outro jeito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos lá. Primeiro você deve criar um método mutator, isto é, que vai alterar o ponteiro "selected". EX:

```
methods: {
   setSelected(index) {
       this.selected = index;   
   }
}
```

No evento `@click` da DIV você deve chamar o mutator, passando o índice da porta.

```
<div class="doors">
    <div
            v-for="i in doorsAmount"
            :key="i"
            @click="setSelected(i)"
            :id="'door' + i"
        >
            <Door :number="i" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Ainda na DIV você deve passar um bind :class para mudar o estilo do elemento de forma condicional, verificando qual o índice ativo:

```
<div v-bind:class="{ 'doorSelected': i == selected }" ... ><Door :number="i" /></div>
```

Sempre que a variável `selected` mudar de valor o DOM vai ser renderizado com o elemento que contém o índice `i` igual a `selected` adicionando a classe `doorSelected` a esse elemento e removendo do anterior

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Oi @isaac-bruno, o problema  é q os componentes estão em arquivos diferentes... então nesse caso no meu arquivo principal eu teria q alterar o dado e a classe que pertencem a outro arquivo, o arquivo do componente porta...

Comment: Se eu jogar o attr e a classe para o principal, vai funcionar nesse caso... Mas e se eu não puder fazer isso? Como eu posso manipular dds e chamar metodos do arq de um outro componente? Tentei colocar o metodo ``setSelected(idx)`` no arq porta e usar ele no principal, aparece no console q o metodo não foi declarado... Da pra fazer essa manipulação em arqs diferentes? E se não der, vc tem alguma ideia pra contornar essa situação? Valeu mesmo ;)

Comment: Nos casos em que você vai usar componentes é só repassar os atributos (class, selected) via bind para os componentes filhos, a partir do componente principal. Vê esse artigo aqui: https://medium.com/@kevinbreaker/comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-componentes-com-vuejs-8fbb1ff075b3

Comment: Funcionou. Agora peguei a logica do Vue. Valeu